How to properly filter by custom metadata (GetItems with POST does not behave as Items with GET) using REST API v1?
I'd like to search for items in a SharePoint list by their custom metadata values or in other words filter a SharePoint list by specifying values for custom metadata fields.
Searching the internet two approaches come up regularly.

Using the "special field" TaxCatchAll/Term with a GET request to /Items(), e.g. /_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items()?$filter=TaxCatchAll/Term eq 'needle'
This does basically work, but has the drawback that all custom meta data fields associated with the list are searched. Since I do have a list with a lot of fields that may contain the same values, this approach is not good enough.

Using a CamlQuery with a POST request to /GetItems(), e.g. /_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/GetItems() and the following body:
{
  "query":{
    "__metadata":{
      "type": "SP.CamlQuery"
    },
    "ViewXml": "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='my_internal_field_name'/><Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>needle</Value></Contains></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>"
  }
}



That CAML request is executed successfully, but I always only get back one result (with the same ID, no matter what I specify - it seems to be the last item added with the highest ID) in the d.results array, despite the fact that the query does match more than one item.
Investigating this, I've noticed that running a POST request without a query using GetItems() does not return the same items as a GET request to Items().
Imo, both of the following requests should return the same number of items.

GET: /_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items()?$select=ID&$orderby=ID&$top=500

POST: /_api/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/GetItems()?$select=ID&$orderby=ID
Body:
{
  "query":{
    "__metadata":{
      "type": "SP.CamlQuery"
    },
    "ViewXml": "<View><Query></Query><RowLimit>500</RowLimit></View>"
  }
}



The first request returns 500 results (as expected, I got thousands of items in that list), but the second request only returns 131 results. The IDs returned in both results do also differ. Therefore, it seems that the /GetItems() request does apply some automatic filtering or is not able to query all items.
While writing this I've also came across the "special field" TaxCatchAll/IdForTerm, but I haven't looked into it yet.
All approaches I tried so far did not work properly. I simply want to query a list by specfifying one or more custom metadata fields and values for these fields.
My question is: How-to properly filter a SharePoint list by custom metadata (Taxonomy, TermSet) fields and values?
